# Converting Spring XML to JavaConfig

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-java-config

I want to convert the following spring beans from xml to a javaconfig class:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="resource"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jaxbMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="resource" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails">
    <property name="username" value="asdfasdf" />
    <property name="password" value="asdfasdfa" />
    <property name="clientId" value="asdfasdf-asdfas-asdfasf" />
    <property name="clientSecret" value="asdfasdf-asdfasdf-adfasdfd" /> 
    <property name="accessTokenUri" value="asdfsadfasd" />
    <property name="grantType" value="password"></property>
    <property name="clientAuthenticationScheme" value="form" />
</bean>
```

How exactly would you convert this? I came across [this example](https://blog.frankel.ch/consider-replacing-spring-xml-configuration-with-javaconfig) but it's kind of confusing because it doesn't really make sense to me how the `<constructor-arg...>` and `<property....>` tags are represented in java. In the example they both translate to:

```
return new JButton(...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring configuration file you need to do this:

```
@Bean
public ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource() {
       ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails  r = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails ();
       r.setUsername("asdfasdf");
    ....

}
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      OAuth2RestTemplate rest = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource());
      rest.setMessageConverters(...);
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConv = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
      messageConv.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
      rest.setMessageConverters(messageConv);
}
```

From the above example you can understand the rules:

1. property can be done with setProperty..
2. Constructor arg is really param in constructor
3. A list is arraylist
4. Depencdecies between beans are like in the example

   Suggestion: If you are trying to achieve something and you don't understand just google it and serach for the specific example.. This will be the easiest way and working by the rules will be easy for you

Comment: how exactly does the `setMessageConverters` work since it's a list?

Comment: Look on my edit, You need to create it according to your convertors

Comment: so this helps me better understand how to convert spring xml to javaconfig. But how would you define a method in xml that takes in 1 input. Something like `public foo(int x)`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand.. Could you give an example? Why do you care about xml you are trying to do it in java right?

Comment: correct but I'm just trying to understand how to the conversion from xml to javaconfig works. What I posted above was a small example. I'm in the process of converting a huge project's xml file into javaconfig so I'm trying to get a good understand of how spring parses an xml and how it's represented in java.

Comment: Updated the answer, you have to take this rules and for specific case you just need to google it.. constructor arg is just param in constructor.

Comment: Does my answer is what you need? could you mark it as resolved?

Comment: In addition: if you inject property from external
<property name="address" value="${cache.provider.address}"
 the solution is annotate a variabile in this way
@Value("${cache.provider.address}")